# EF Core7 , RemoteCertificateValidationCallback error was throwd in docker container

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, ef-core-7.0

I have this connection string:

```
server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1432;database=DbName;user id=sa;password=DbPassword123;TrustServerCertificate=True;
```

I use .NET 7 and EF Core 7 - it works fine on my local PC.

But when I run this project in a Docker container, it throws this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
>
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.

I use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Project.Api/Project.Api.csproj", "Project.Api/"]
COPY ["Project.Module.Admin/Project.Module.Admin.csproj", "Project.Module.Admin/"]
COPY ["Project.Module.Shared/Project.Module.Shared.csproj", "Project.Module.Shared/"]
COPY ["Project.Data/Project.Data.csproj", "Project.Data/"]
COPY ["Project.Infrastructure/Project.Infrastructure.csproj", "Project.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Project.Identity/Project.Identity.csproj", "Project.Identity/"]
COPY ["Project.Job/Project.Job.csproj", "Project.Job/"]
COPY ["Project.Module.Driver/Project.Module.Driver.csproj", "Project.Module.Driver/"]
COPY ["Project.Module.User/Project.Module.User.csproj", "Project.Module.User/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Project.Api/Project.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Project.Api"
RUN dotnet build "Project.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Project.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.Api.dll"]
```

And this docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.4"
services:
  db-production:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest"
    container_name: db-production
    restart: always
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "DbPassword123"
    volumes:
      - /home/volumes/mssql/data/production:/var/opt/mssql/data
    ports:
      - "1432:1433"
  backend-production:
    image: "backend_production:${TAG}"
    container_name: backend-production
    environment:
      - "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Project.Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "${EXPOSED_PORT_PRODUCTION}:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db-production
```

I expected it's working fine same as my local PC on docker container

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue for Ef-core 7 on Git Hub. If you downgrade the version to 6.x.x, it works fine on docker.

```
https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1856
```

Comment: this is my issue on GitHub :)